# Can we use the same job id after BigQuery cached query results expire?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery's typical cache lifetime is 24 hours, but the cached results are best-effort and may be invalidated sooner.

Does BigQuery re-fetch the results if we try to get results using the job id whose cached results expired?

Comment: obviously, it will not! so you will need to issue your query job again

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant In that case, what will be the status of the result? Could it be "status": "success" or something else? And would it be possible to reuse the query associated with the job id by using the same job id only?

Comment: I think it is something you can easily try by yourself and let all of us know :o)  But most likely you will get 404 with Not found ...

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I do mean to try but while waiting for the cache to expire in the next 24 hours, I just tried posting the question to see if anyone already ran the same experiment. I also searched in the documentation. Thanks

Comment: see my previous comment. to be 100% sure that we are talking about same thing  - do you mean calling`getQueryResults` with that jobid?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yeah "404 with Not found" sounds likely. Yes, I'm using "getQueryResults()". I will post my outcome tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean calling `getQueryResults` job with jobid of job which result has expired - you will get 404 with message: "Not found: Job "

Comment: This is consistent with my finding

{
    "status": "failure",
    "format": "job",
    "reason": "notFound"
}

Comment: great, thank you for confirming. consider also voting up the answer if not yet o)